Dynamically updated choices list doesn't appear in forms in formset in Django
I am on Django 5.1.1. In IngredientForm in IngredientFormSet, I have 2 fields - name (ChoiceField with id as value) and unit (ChoiceField). Based on the id, the unit can be 'g' (grams) or 'mL' if liquid, or just 'g' if solid.
class IngredientForm(forms.Form):
    ingredient = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Ingredient name',
        required=True,
        choices=[],
    )
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()
    unit = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        choices=[('g', 'g')]
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.is_bound:
            form_ingredient_id = self['ingredient'].value()
            try:
                form_ingredient = Ingredient.objects_all.get(
                    id=form_ingredient_id
                )
                if form_ingredient.is_liquid:
                    self.fields['unit'].choices.append(('mL', 'mL'))
            except (Ingredient.DoesNotExist):
                pass


In the view, the updated form choice field seems to update correctly:
def myview(request):
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        IngredientsFormSet = formset_factory(IngredientForm)
        ingredient_formset = IngredientsFormSet(
            request.POST, prefix='ingredientform'
        )
        # ...

    for form in ingredient_formset:
        print(form.fields['unit'].choices)
        # [('g', 'g'), ('mL', 'mL')]
    context({'ingredient_formset': ingredient_formset})

    return TemplateResponse(request, some_template_path, context)

This is my template:
{% for form in ingredient_formset %}
  <div class="row form-row">
    <div class="col-7">{{ form.ingredient }}</div>
    <div class="col-1">{{ form.unit }}</div>
    <div class="col-4">{% for choice_val, choice_txt in form.fields.unit.choices %}{{ choice_val }}-{{ choice_txt }} {% endfor %}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

{{ form.unit }} only displays 'g' in the dropdown, whereas form.fields.unit.choices shows 'g' and 'mL'. Not able to figure out what I have missed to update in the dynamic choice.

That I am updating the choices list was the problem. I needed to set the choices fully, as there is a setter method in ChoiceField class that updated the widget_choices that has direct connection to what is actually shown in the dropdown.
The correct code:
if form_ingredient.is_liquid:
    self.fields['unit'].choices = [('g', 'g'), ('mL', 'mL')]

